# Pentaho 8.1 multi-tenancy

Tags: pentaho, multi-tenant

I've tried to follow the documentation ([Pentaho Multi-Tenancy](https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/8.1/Developer_Center/Multi-Tenancy)) but the way they did isn't exactly what I need, they still use only one repository. I'm trying to find a way to make the server use one repository for each tenant. Is that possible?

I've found some classes like: Tenant ([Tenant (pentaho-platform-core 8.1.0.0-365 API)](https://javadoc.pentaho.com/bi-platform810/pentaho-platform-core-8.1.0.0-365-javadoc/org/pentaho/platform/core/mt/Tenant.html)) and RepositoryTenantManager ([RepositoryTenantManager (pentaho-platform-repository 8.1.0.0-365 API)](https://javadoc.pentaho.com/bi-platform810/pentaho-platform-repository-8.1.0.0-365-javadoc/org/pentaho/platform/repository2/mt/RepositoryTenantManager.html) ). The documentation about them is vague, are they used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you can’t. Pentaho uses only one repo, at most you can limit what each user can see and onky show elements of the right tenant.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to find another solution then :/